# Java trying to execute git command from mingw32

Tags: java, windows, git, mingw32

i try to execute git command which is installed in my windows 
(bitbucket mingw32 git )

the command:

```
  Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\My\\AppData\\Local\\Atlassian\\SourceTree\\git_local\\mingw32\\bin");
        try {
            Utils.runCommand(path,
                "git.exe",
                            "-C",
                            "c:/product/my_project",
                            "clone",
                            "-b",
                              "develop","https://my_user_name@bitbucket.org/myproject/my_project.git");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

the code which execute the git :

```
public static void runCommand(Path directory, String... command) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Objects.requireNonNull(directory, "directory");
        if (!Files.exists(directory)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("can't run command in non-existing directory '" + directory + "'");
        }
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder()
                .command(command)
                .directory(directory.toFile());
        Process p = pb.start();
        StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler(p.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");
        StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new StreamGobbler(p.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT");
        outputGobbler.start();
        errorGobbler.start();
        int exit = p.waitFor();
        errorGobbler.join();
        outputGobbler.join();
        if (exit != 0) {
            throw new AssertionError(String.format("runCommand returned %d", exit));
        }
    }

    private static class StreamGobbler extends Thread {

        private final InputStream is;
        private final String type;

        private StreamGobbler(InputStream is, String type) {
            this.is = is;
            this.type = type;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));) {
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(type + "> " + line);
                }
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

getting error:

```
ERROR> Cloning into 'my_project'...
ERROR> bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
ERROR> error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
ERROR> fatal: could not read Password for 'https://user@bitbucket.org': Invalid argument
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: runCommand returned 128
    at Utils.runCommand(Utils.java:71)
    at Main.main(tester.java:38)
```